# Git - prevent files from git pull/clone but let live in the Source

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have taken over a new project and three files in that project were put into the repository long back. We figured that those files are useless now. I don't want to remove those files from the source but I don't want them to download as well when I do git clone or pull from a branch.

PS - the files are in master branch. Is there any way to stop these files from downloading to local and just let live on the repo?

Comment: Why not delete them? That's a part of Git's main attraction. If you delete it today you can look up your history in 3 months time and restore them.

Comment: oh so if I delete will itnot completely destroy from the source?

Comment: No, Git is a version control system nothing in Git is ever lost. Everything is tracked in some way as long as you've committed or stashed them. Try `git log -p` It will show you for each commit how the files were changed over time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you add this as answer?

Comment: https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/